# Screen sharing with video and ability for users to draw on screen

Tags: chat, video-conferencing, screen-sharing

I am looking for a combination of the features in Slack and Google Hangout:

In table form:

```
+------------------------------------------------+-------+-----------------+----+
|                    Feature                     | Slack | Google Hangouts | ?? |
+------------------------------------------------+-------+-----------------+----+
| Video calling                                  | X     | X               | X  |
| Screen sharing                                 | X     | X               | X  |
| Users can draw on top of shared screen         | X     |                 | X  |
| Text chat                                      | X     | X               | X  |
| Video remains on for user presenting           |       | X               | X  |
| Available on Win/OSX (web is ok)               | X     | X               | X  |
| Price < 20$/mo per user                        | X     | X               | X  |
+------------------------------------------------+-------+-----------------+----+
```

Which product fits in the last column by meeting all the requirements?

Comment: For which OS? What price limit?

Comment: @Izzy regarding OS it is already in the table (available on Win/OSX, web ok). I added price.

Comment: Ah, missed that – and thanks for the addition! Table view is quite unusual here (nothing wrong with it, just unusual :) Good luck then!

Comment: Thanks, I think the table view is more easily glanceable - and it also explains why Slack or Hangouts does not meet the requirements. :)